# Creat streamlines from a steady flow field in C

Tags: c, vector, field

I'm currently trying to create some streamlines from a vector field for a program I'm currently making. I've so far tried NaST2D but discovered that it's for non-steady streams and a lot more than just calculating streamlines. My questions is if there are any (fairly lightweight) c librarys or sourcecodes for making streamlines.

Comment: you will probably have a better luck posting your question here http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And they said that the questions was off topic :P

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for library recommendations is normally considered offtopic here.